# Ruby on rails windows installed using railsInstaller fails to install gems / bundles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have an existing project which is stored on bitbucket, and just cloned that onto my windows box.

I enter the main project directory and run

```
rails server
```

I get the message:

```
Could not find rake-10.4.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

so I run bundle install - which responds:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I run command

```
gem install rake -v '10.4.1'
```

Which responds:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.4.1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I read some other posts and people were asked to run this command:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
```

Which responds:

```
"OpenSSL 1.0.0o 15 Oct 2014"
```

Please can somebody guide me as to what is wrong here!

Comment: I resolved a similar issue on my Windows machine by updating RubyGems. By hand, downloaded a zip and ran an installer script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be some longstanding issue with Ruby on windows.

I solved it by following these windows fix instructions:

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: Thanks a lot lot :) I 've been struggling to install rails on my system .. Finally DONE !!